# Coloring the background of each quadrant in a scatter plot with a different color

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I produce this scatter plot:

```
plot(x = runif(20,-10,10), y = runif(20,-10,10), xlim = c(-10,10), ylim = c(-10,10))
abline(h = 0, col = "black")
abline(v = 0, col = "black")
```

So the `abline`'s divide the plane to the four Cartesian quadrants.
I would like to color the background of each quadrant in a different color. Say blue, red, green, and yellow for quadrants 1-4, respectively.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using base graphics so here's a base graphics solution.

Write a function that uses `rect` and gets the plot limits from `par()$usr`:

```
quads =
function(colours=c("blue","red","green","yellow")){
  limits = par()$usr
  rect(0,0,limits[2],limits[4],col=colours[1])
  rect(0,0,limits[1],limits[4],col=colours[2])
  rect(0,0,limits[1],limits[3],col=colours[3])
  rect(0,0,limits[2],limits[3],col=colours[4])
}
```

Note you have to do this before plotting your points or it splats over them. Using `type='n'` in a plot function will set up an empty plot with some data:

```
> x = runif(20,-10,10) ; y = runif(20,-10,10)
> plot(x,y,type="n")
> quads()
> points(x,y)
```

Specify your own colours via the `colours=` arg.

Answer (score 8):

If you like a ggplot solution:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(20,-10,10), y = runif(20,-10,10))
    ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = Inf, xmax = 0, ymin = Inf, ymax = 0, fill= "red")  + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 0, ymin = -Inf, ymax = 0 , fill= "blue") + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0, ymax = -Inf, fill= "yellow") + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = -Inf, ymin = Inf, ymax = 0, fill= "green") + 
      geom_point() + xlim(-10,10)+ ylim(-10,10)
```

[image]

#### Edit:

@Spacedman: I didn't know some devices can have problems with Inf here a function that does not use Inf, and also allows the choice of the crossing point and colors of the quadrants

```
colquad <- function(plot, crossAt = 0, xlims = c(-10,10), ylims = c(-10,10), colours = c("blue", "red","yellow", "green")) {
  #colours of rects are from left to right starting at the top
    library(ggplot2)
    plot <- plot + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(xlims[1],xlims[2]), ylim = c(ylims[1], ylims[2])) 
    plot + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = xlims[1], xmax = crossAt, ymin = ylims[2], ymax = crossAt, fill = colours[1]) + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = crossAt, xmax = xlims[2], ymin = crossAt, ymax = ylims[2], fill = colours[2])  +
      annotate("rect", xmin = xlims[1], xmax = crossAt, ymin = ylims[1], ymax = crossAt , fill= colours[3]) + 
      annotate("rect", xmin = crossAt, xmax = xlims[2], ymin = crossAt, ymax = ylims[1], fill = colours[4]) + 
      geom_point()
  }
```

To use it (to make the previous graphs):

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(20,-10,10), y = runif(20,-10,10))
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))
colquad(plot)
```

And an example of the advantage of ggplot2, change colour of the points to white

`colquad(plot) %+% geom_point(colour = "white")`

Comment: I don't like using `Inf` when creating graphics - some graphics drivers can have problems with it. Is there any way you can get the axis limits and draw the rectangles according to that? (analagous to getting `par()$usr` as in my answer)

Comment: I really like the function-way of approaching R problems ... 2 beers for you @BBrill !!